# Exporting Animation Blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, export, blender, fbx

I am trying to use my animation which I made in blender.

It works fine in bot Blender and Windows .fbx opener but not working.

There are 12 bones and just one of them works, but normal of the meshes are inverted and not work properly.

I have used NLA editor for exporting. Could you help me. What should I do?

[Blender and Unity Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kx1p.png)

Comment: Is it actually an animation problem or just a problem with the normals?

Comment: Both animation and normals are problems. But when I export my animation as reversed. Animation problem working okay as reversed (interesting). But the normals inversed. So, I applied double-sided material to fix this issue and apply a code to turn animation to straighten out the reverse.

Comment: blender renders materials doublesided. You can see the direction of the normal by activating the "Display Normals" option in the "Viewport overlays". You can select the faces that have inverted normal in blender press alt+n -> Flip. perhaps it is all you need to do.

Comment: Actually when I try to change the normals with shift+n. Half of the face's normals are being inverted and others are okay. It is really weird. So I applied this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `.blend` file into unity project. Unity then somehow imports it automatically (no need to export it at all).

Comment: I would definitely try it. Thanks